# Count patterns and differentiate them

Tags: r, count, stringr, find-occurrences

I'd like to count a defined pattern (here: 'Y') in a string for each row of a dataframe. Ideally, I'd like to get a number of occurrences in V3 and length in V4.

Input:

```
V1  V2
A   XXYYYYY
B   XXYYXX
C   XYXXYX
D   XYYXYX
```

Output:

```
V1       V2 V3   V4
 A  XXYYYYY  1    5
 B   XXYYXX  1    2
 C   XYXXYX  2  1,1
 D   XYYXYX  2  2,1
```

I tried different modifications of the function below, with no success.

```
dict <- setNames(nm=c("Y"))
seqs <- df$V2
sapply(dict, str_count, string=seqs)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `str_` functions should all be vectorised I believe. No need to `sapply` them. Also, `gregexpr("Y", df$V2)` should essentially give this in base R.

Comment: thanks, but you solution gives position of 'Y', not number of occurrences and/or length

Comment: @thelatemail If you change the pattern to `"Y+"` the match length will be captured correctly.

Comment: @steveb - true, I forgot the `+` there.

Comment: @user2904120 The last row of your output 'D' is missing a 'Y' (see the input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `stringr` solution:

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  V2 = c("XXYYYYY", "XXYYXX" , "XYXXYX", "XYYXYX")
  )

df$V3 <- str_count(df$V2, "Y+")

df$V4 <- lapply(str_locate_all(df$V2, "Y+"), function(x) {
    paste(x[, 2] - x[, 1] + 1, collapse = ",")
  })
```

Comment: in df$V3 <- str_count(df$V2, "Y+") how to specify a random character, e.g. Y*Y, so the search comes up with XYYXYX that contains YXY

Answer (score 2):

another base R solution but using `regexpr`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  V2 = c("XXYYYYY", "XXYYXX" , "XYXXYX", "XYYXYX")
)
```

extract `match.length` attribute of the `regexpr` output, then count length of each attribute (which tells you how many matches there are):

```
r <- gregexpr("Y+", df$V2)
len <- lapply(r, FUN = function(x) as.array((attributes(x)[[1]])))
df$V3 <- lengths(len)
df$V4 <- len

df
#V1      V2 V3   V4
#1  A XXYYYYY  1    5
#2  B  XXYYXX  1    2
#3  C  XYXXYX  2 1, 1
#4  D  XYYXYX  2 2, 1
```

if you have an old version of R that doesn't have `lengths` yet you can use `df$V3 <- sapply(len, length)` instead.
and if you need a more generic function to do the same for any vector `x` and pattern `a`:

```
foo <- function(x, a){
  ans <- data.frame(x)
  r <- gregexpr(a, x)
  len <- lapply(r, FUN = function(z) as.array((attributes(z)[[1]])))
  ans$quantity <- lengths(len)
  ans$lengths <- len
  ans
}
```

try `foo(df$V2, 'Y+')`.

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```
aaa <- data.frame(V1 = LETTERS[1:4], 
                  V2 = c("XXYYYYY", "XXYYXX", "XYXXYX", "XYYXYX"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# split into strings of "Y"s
splt <- lapply(aaa$V2, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "[^Y]+"))[-1])

# number of occurrences
aaa$V3 <- lapply(splt, length)

# length of each occurence
aaa$V4 <- lapply(splt, function(x) paste(nchar(x), collapse = ","))
```

Comment: any idea how to run it as one function, so one can simply specify a pattern e.g. "Y" , "YY", or "X" ?

Comment: @user2904120 see my answer below for a function